# Selenium + TestNG testing a serie of webpages

Tags: selenium, testng

I'm just starting with TestNG and Selenium

I want to perform a registration test in a collection of webpages.
I've writen a Register class with the following methods

```
@Test( dataProvider = "WebSites", groups = "launchSite")
public void launchSite(WeboSite webSite)

@Test( dataProvider = "WebSites", groups = "goToRegPage",
       dependsOnGroups = "launchSite")
public void openRegisterPage(WeboSite webSite)

@Test( dataProvider = "WebSites", groups = "register",
   dependsOnGroups = "goToRegPage")
public void enterRegistrationData(BingoSite bingoSite)
```

So I've made each test dependant on the previous (obviously if you cannot enter the registration page you cannot register)
What I want now is each webpage result be independant from the others.
Now *openRegisterPage* is run for every webpage and if it fails in one website *enterRegistrationData* is not run for any of them.

What is the correct way to do this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I've reading a bit here and there, I think I might need to use selenium grid to solve this

Answer (score 0):

If a method fails, all the methods that depend on it will be skipped, that's the point of this feature.

You can specify alwaysRun=true on enterRegistrationData, if that's what you want (not quite clear from your question).

Comment: Ok, I'll try to make it clearer. Lets say I have two websites, websiteA and websiteB. launchSite is run for both websites, both pass, then openRegisterPage is run for both pages, pass on websiteA and fails on websiteB, then enterRegistrationData is skipped for both websites, it should be run on websiteA

So what I want is tests for every website be independent of the other websites.

Comment: Apparently TestNG 6.02 beta solves that: http://testng.org/beta But tests are run in amplitude order.